# Upgrade Dell T320 Perc h310 Raid to h710 resulted in lost datastore

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge, dell-perc, datastore

I am in trouble!

So we bought this server a year and a half ago.  Its a Dell T320.  It came with a Perc h310 Raid card.  I'll be honest I messed up the install.  I didn't know about the SD cards and VMWare coming on them or anything.  When the system arrived I setup a Raid 5 with a hot spare.  I then proceeded to install Vmware onto the Raid.  I changed the boot order and booted to it and that was that.

A year and a half later we have noticed all along horrible latency problems copying files between VM's and out to network and so on.  I did some googling to find out Raid h310 is rubbish and I should upgrade to a h710 which is compatible and will not lose data in doing so.

So we ordered it.  I powered the server down.  I unplugged the old card.  I plugged in the new h710.  I powered it back on and went into raid config (Ctrl R).  There was the raid, optimal state everything looks fine.  I enable adaptive read ahead and write back caching and reboot the server.  It proceeds to boot to vmware 4.1.  I had installed 5!  After an hour of scratching my head and having no VM's or anything I get to thinking this was the first server I setup and I think I set it up wrong.  I change the boot order to the Raid, but it doesn't matter, it still boots to the dang SD cards which is nothing but a blank install with no datastore.

So my problem...
1. When 4.1 boots of the SD cards, there is no datastore.  I can see the RAID card in configuration but when attempting to add a datstore it wants to create a new one.  I cannot afford to lose this data.
2. How come when I boot to the raid the VMware 5 is not booting?!?  If the raid is intact which it sure appears to be, it should be there!

I am unsure how to proceed.  Admittedly I don't have backups of "all" the VMs only 2 of them.  I need to get it to boot to the VMware that I installed.

Can I install Vmware 5 or higher on the SD cards and import the datastore?  I will probably try this as the SD card install is empty as it is...

Please advise

Comment: meant to post an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

So upon checking the boot sequence again I had only change 1 of the two options.  I had changed the C drive to be first in boot order but I also had to change lower down that the raid was first boot device.  Upon doing that vmware 5 booted up and I was able to reattach the datastore and all was right with the world.  However, since I did it wrong the first time I am fixing my mistakes.  I used VMWare workstation to download the 4 VM's to my local PC, installed Dells VMWare 6.0 custom ISO to the SD cards, attached the datastore on them and am running all 4 machines through VMware converter to upgrade their hardware version and change them to thin provisioned instead of thick.